# Problem in content assist in Spring tool suite

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have imported a project in spring tool suite,i am not able to get the content assist ,i am getting an error "project not found in build path".

Answer (score 0):

Check that your build paths are set up correctly for the project you imported. It may be the case that the imported project is expecting another project to also be present but that is not there.